# How to do a Yule-Walker analysis in Julia

Tags: statistics, time-series, julia

Is there a method in Julia to perform a Yule-Walker analysis similar to the equivalent method in Python [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.yule_walker](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.yule_walker.html) ?

Comment: Looking at python code in the link supplied, it seems pretty straightforward to implement in Julia, perhaps with the help of ToeplitzMatrices package.

Comment: @DanGetz, However, that's a little bit odd since they've not talked about `method=mle`. Seems either `adjusted` or `mle` would result in the same.

Comment: @Shayan `adj_needed = method == "adjusted"` and `(n - k * adj_needed)` in the python code manage the adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, as recommended, I have implemented it myself, and the code is like this. I have tested it for some cases, and the results are the same as those of the Python function.

```
function yule_walker(
    x::Vector{Float64};
    order::Int64=1,
    method="adjusted",
    df::Union{Nothing,Int64}=nothing,
    inv=false,
    demean=true,
)
    method in ("adjusted", "mle") ||
        throw(ArgumentError("ACF estimation method must be 'adjusted' or 'MLE'"))

    x = copy(x)
    if demean
        x .-= mean(x)
    end
    n = isnothing(df) ? length(x) : df

    adj_needed = method == "adjusted"

    if ndims(x) > 1 || size(x, 2) != 1
        throw(ArgumentError("Expecting a vector to estimate AR parameters"))
    end

    r = zeros(Float64, order + 1)
    r[1] = sum(x .^ 2) / n
    for k = 1:order
        r[k+1] = sum(x[1:end-k] .* x[k+1:end]) / (n - k * adj_needed)
    end
    R = Toeplitz(r[1:(end - 1)], conj(r[1:(end - 1)]))

    rho = 0
    try
        rho = R \ r[2:end]
    catch err
        if occursin("Singular matrix", string(err))
            @warn "Matrix is singular. Using pinv."
            rho = pinv(R) * r[2:end]
        else
            throw(err)
        end
    end

    sigmasq = r[1] - dot(r[2:end], rho)
    sigma = isnan(sigmasq) || sigmasq <= 0 ? NaN : sqrt(sigmasq)

    if inv
        return rho, sigma, inv(R)
    else
        return rho, sigma
    end
end
```

It's tested for these cases,

```
tol = 1e-5
@testset "yule_walker" begin
    rho, sigma = yule_walker([1.0, 2, 3]; order=1)
    @test rho == [0.0]

    rho, sigma = yule_walker([1.0, 2, 3]; order=2)
    @test rho == [0.0, -1.5]

    x = [0.9901178, -0.74795127, 0.44612542, 1.1362954, -0.04040932]
    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=3, method="mle")
    @test rho ≈ [-0.9418963, -0.90335955, -0.33267884]
    @test sigma ≈ 0.44006365345695164

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=3)
    @test isapprox(rho, [0.10959317, 0.05242324, 1.06587676], atol=tol)
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.15860522671108127, atol=tol)

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=5, method="mle")
    @test isapprox(
        rho, [-1.24209771, -1.56893346, -1.16951484, -0.79844781, -0.27598787], atol=tol
    )
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.3679474002175471, atol=tol)

    x = [
        0.9901178,
        -0.74795127,
        0.44612542,
        1.1362954,
        -0.04040932,
        0.28625813,
        0.88901716,
        -0.1079814,
        -0.33231995,
        0.4607741,
    ]

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=3, method="mle")
    @test isapprox(
        rho, [-0.4896151627237206, -0.5724647370433921, 0.09083516892540627], atol=tol
    )
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.4249693094713215, atol=tol)

    x = [
        0.9901178,
        -0.74795127,
        0.44612542,
        1.1362954,
        -0.04040932,
        0.28625813,
        0.88901716,
        -0.1079814,
        -0.33231995,
        0.4607741,
        0.7729643,
        -1.0998684,
        1.098167,
        1.0105597,
        -1.3370227,
        1.239718,
        -0.01393661,
        -0.4790918,
        1.5009186,
        -1.1647809,
    ]

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=3, method="mle")
    @test isapprox(rho, [-0.82245705, -0.57029742, 0.12166898], atol=tol)
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.5203501608988023, atol=tol)

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=3)
    @test isapprox(rho, [-0.93458149, -0.68653741, 0.10161722], atol=tol)
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.4269012058667671, atol=tol)

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=5, method="mle")
    @test isapprox(
        rho, [-0.83107755, -0.56407764, 0.20950143, 0.1232321, 0.10249279], atol=tol
    )
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.5172269743102993, atol=tol)

    rho, sigma = yule_walker(x; order=5)
    @test isapprox(
        rho, [-0.96481241, -0.65359486, 0.31587079, 0.28403115, 0.1913565], atol=tol
    )
    @test isapprox(sigma, 0.41677565377507053, atol=tol)
end;
```

Comment: Maybe finding the right place to contribute this function will be even better than a stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment on this [PR](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/pull/902), you can compute the Yule-Walker estimates efficiently by reusing existing functions from JuliaStats.jl. Then, there is no need to add this functionality.